How to delete soft deleted buckets in Google Cloud Storage?
Preamble:
I have a Google App Engine website, and I'm having a problem where I'm being billed for no reason. In the cost table, it says the cost comes from a "Standard Storage US Multi-region", which in weird because my buckets are in South America, which are free because the project is also in SA, or something like that. Then I remembered that, every time I deploy the app, a "us.artifacts.luiz-zeroxis.appspot.com" bucket appears. Normally, I just delete it immediately after building, because for some reason this bucket does cost money. It would be great if I could just change the region of it and be done with it, but that doesn't seem possible.
This wasn't a problem, but recently it has been. I don't remember how I though about it, but I believe the problem is the new "soft delete" option that they added, which is being applied to this artifacts bucket and using up storage in the background. I already disabled all manners of soft deleting settings anywhere I could find, but somehow this one just keeps being there. I can't find much information on this in the interface, other than this in the monitoring tab: It shows 2.47 GiB in "soft-deleted-object us"!
Question:
Using the command gcloud storage ls --buckets --soft-deleted --full, it shows 3 buckets (or rather, 3 versions of the same bucket) with the name "gs://us.artifacts.luiz-zeroxis.appspot.com/", with various hard delete times in the future.
So: How can I delete these buckets permanently right now? And ideally, how can I make so it doesn't happen again?

Your existing soft-deleted buckets will be permanently deleted only after the soft delete retention duration ends, which is 7 days by default.
However, you can change this default for new buckets by using tags. Specifically, you should set the default soft delete retention duration for your project to 0. After this, all new buckets in the project will have a soft delete retention duration of 0, which means that they will not be retained after they are deleted and you won't be charged.

That has not worked. I set up the tag as in the documentation, but it didn't seem to affect this. It shows this:
  {
    "effectiveTime": "2024-12-19T01:54:49.174000+00:00",
    "retentionDurationSeconds": "604800"
  }```

According to the documentation, this tag can take several hours to take effect. So you might need to give it some time. Otherwise, you can contact customer support, and they can look into your specific situation.

Actually I did the tag thing like a week ago, I didn't want to bother without actually testing an update. I guess I'll try contacting them (if you can even do that without paying).
